# how to merge two strings ordered alphabetically, using recursion

Tags: recursion, merge, lisp, common-lisp

I am learning Lisp. I have implemented a Common Lisp function that merges two strings that are ordered alphabetically, using recursion. Here is my code, but there is something wrong with it and I didn't figure it out.

```
(defun merge (F L)
    (if (null F)
        (if (null L)
            F         ; return f
            ( L ))    ; else return L
        ;else if
        (if (null L)
            F)        ; return F
    ;else if
    (if (string< (substring F 0 1) (substring L 0 1)
        (concat 'string (substring F 0 1) 
                        (merge (substring F 1 (length F)) L)))
    ( 
        (concat 'string (substring L 0 1) 
                        (merge F (substring L 1 (length L)) ))
    ))))
```

Edit :
I simply want to merge two strings such as the
inputs are string `a = adf` and string `b = beg`
and the result or output should be `abdefg`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: or is there a better way to do?

Comment: You should describe what errors you're getting and exactly what's not working.  Providing a small test case with what you want and what it's actually doing is also good.

Comment: I edited. When I run this code using sbcl; the error is; error while parsing arguments to special form IF:
;     invalid number of elements in
;       ((NULL F)
;        (IF (NULL L)
;            F
;            (L))
;        (IF (NULL L)
;            F)
;        (IF (STRING< (SUBSTRING F 0 1) (SUBSTRING L 0 1) (CONCAT 'STRING # #))
;            ((CONCAT 'STRING # #))))
;     to satisfy lambda list
;       (SB-C::TEST SB-C::THEN &OPTIONAL SB-C::ELSE):
;     between 2 and 3 expected, but 4 found

Comment: since I am new in lisp, I don't even sure that the return parts of the code is correct.

Comment: could you please format the code correctly?

Comment: `(L)` will *call* `L` with 0 arguments. Remove all your extraneous parentheses as a first step. Also, there's no need to have a space after opening parenthesis. It makes your code very hard to read. If you want to return `L`, call `(return L)`, not just `L`, if not in terminal position.

Comment: next, mind the types of your values. `null` is meaningful to call on lists, to check whether they are empty or not, not on strings. `(null "")` returns `NIL`. `(length "")` returns 0. The full name of the function you're using is `concatenate`, not `concat`. But before all, please format your code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your comments, it looks like you're trying to use `if` with a series of conditions (like a series of `else if`s in some other languages). For that, you probably want [cond](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/LispText/lisp-cond.html).

I replaced that `if` with `cond` and cleaned up some other errors, and it worked.

```
(defun empty (s) (= (length s) 0))

(defun my-merge (F L)
  (cond 
   ((empty F)
    (if (empty L)
      F 
      L)) 
   ((empty L)
    F)
   (t
    (if (string< (subseq F 0 1) (subseq L 0 1))
      (concatenate 'string (subseq F 0 1) (my-merge (subseq F 1 (length F)) L)) 
      (concatenate 'string (subseq L 0 1) (my-merge F (subseq L 1 (length L))))))))
```

Your test case came out as you wanted it to:

```
* (my-merge "adf" "beg")

"abdefg"
```

Comment: the first clause in the `cond` is unnecessarily complex. `L` can just be returned in any case.

Comment: @Will: That's true. I thought it would be more helpful just to get the original code to work first, but I can add that to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using `string<` is an overkill, `char<` should be used instead, as shown by Kaz. Recalculating `length` at each step would make this algorithm quadratic, so should be avoided. Using `sort` to "fake it" makes it O(n log n) instead of O(n). Using `concatenate 'string` all the time probably incurs extra costs of unneeded traversals too.

Here's a natural recursive solution:

```
(defun str-merge (F L)
  (labels ((g (a b)
             (cond
               ((null a)  b)
               ((null b)  a)
               ((char<  (car b)  (car a))
                  (cons  (car b)  (g a (cdr b))))
               (t (cons  (car a)  (g (cdr a) b))))))
    (coerce (g  (coerce F 'list) (coerce L 'list))
            'string)))
```

But, Common Lisp does not have a [tail call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) optimization guarantee, let alone [tail recursion modulo cons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons) optimization guarantee *(even if the latter was described [**as early as 1974**](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-bin/techreports/TRNNN.cgi?trnum=TR19), using "Lisp 1.6's `rplaca` and `rplacd` field assignment operators")*. So we must hand-code this as a top-down output list building loop:

```
(defun str-merge (F L &aux (s (list nil)) )     ; head sentinel
  (do ((p s                (cdr p))
       (a (coerce F 'list) (if q  a  (cdr a)))
       (b (coerce L 'list) (if q (cdr b)  b ))
       (q nil))
      ((or (null a) (null b))
         (if a (rplacd p a) (rplacd p b))
         (coerce (cdr s) 'string))              ;         FTW!
    (setq q  (char<  (car b)  (car a)))   ; the test result
    (if q
      (rplacd p (list (car b)))
      (rplacd p (list (car a))))))
```

Comment: You can use macros (like tailprog) to rewrite your code into guaranteed tail recursion. Here: http://www.kylheku.com/cgit/lisp-snippets/tree/tail-recursion.lisp   There is no example usage of `tailprog`, but it basically looks like `labels`. Some examples occur in archived Usenet discussion.

Comment: PS. since `go` is an operator in Common Lisp, you should not use it as the name of a function. Your code can break macros which use `go` in their macro expansion. Speaking of which, the `tailprog` macro will actually expand your tail recursive calls to `(go ...)`.

Comment: @Kaz thanks, forgot about that. :) On second thought, it's my code, and I don't use macros which use `go`. I don't have tagbody (or what's the name) here either (explicit, at least...). So can I just leave it as it is?

Comment: @Kaz oh I get it, you meant *in general*. About `tailprog`, does it handle tail-rec-mod-cons? Just TCO isn't enough here I think.

Comment: Tail calls under tailprog do not return under any circumstances, so code which expects to be able to `cons` something onto the return value will not work.

Answer (score 2):

There were quite a few good answers, so why would I add one more? Well, the below is probably more efficient then the other answers here.

```
(defun merge-strings (a b)
  (let* ((lena (length a))
         (lenb (length b))
         (len (+ lena lenb))
         (s (make-string len)))
    (labels
        ((safe-char< (x y)
           (if (and x y) (char< x y)
               (not (null x))))
         (choose-next (x y)
           (let ((ax (when (< x lena) (aref a x)))
                 (by (when (< y lenb) (aref b y)))
                 (xy (+ x y)))
             (cond
               ((= xy len) s)
               ((safe-char< ax by)
                (setf (aref s xy) ax)
                (choose-next (1+ x) y))
               (t
                (setf (aref s xy) by)
                (choose-next x (1+ y)))))))
      (choose-next 0 0))))

(merge-strings "adf" "beg")
```

It is more efficient specifically in the sense of memory allocations - it only allocates enough memory to write the result string, never coerces anything (from list to string or from array to string etc.) It may not look very pretty, but this is because it is trying to do every calculation only once.

This is, of course, not the most efficient way to write this function, but programming absolutely w/o efficiency in mind is not going to get you far.

Answer (score -1):

A recursive way to do it (fixed according to comment- other solutions can get an IF form as well).

```
(defun merge-strings (a b)
  (concatenate 'string
               (merge-strings-under a b)))

(defun merge-strings-under (a b)
  (when (and
       (= (length a)
          (length b))
       (> (length a) 0))
    (append (if (string< (aref a 0) (aref b 0))
                (list (aref a 0) (aref b 0))
                (list (aref b 0) (aref a 0)))
            (merge-strings-under (subseq a 1)
                           (subseq b 1)))))
```

---

Here's a iterative way to do it.

```
(concatenate 'string 
    (loop for i across "adf" for j across "beg" nconc (list i j)))
```

Note that these rely on building the string into a list of characters, then vectorizing it ( a string is a vector of characters).

You can also write a more C-esque approach...

```
(defun merge-strings-vector (a b)
  (let ((retstr (make-array (list (+
                                   (length a)
                                   (length b)))
                            :element-type 'character)))
    (labels ((merge-str (a b i)
               (when (and
                    (= (length a)
                       (length b))
                    (/= i (length a)))
                 (setf (aref retstr (* 2 i)) (aref a i))
                 (setf (aref retstr (1+ (* 2 i))) (aref b i))
                 (merge-str a b (1+ i)))))

      (merge-str a b 0)
      retstr)))
```

Note that this one - unlike the other 2 - has side effects within the function. It also, imo, is more difficult to understand.

All 3 take varying numbers of cycles to execute on SBCL 56; each seems to take between 6K and 11K on most of my trials. I'm not sure why.

Comment: could you please explain your recursive solution?

Comment: I think your recursive code doesn't work correctly. When I run this code with the arguments "abc" and "def", the output is (#\a #\d #\b #\e #\c #\f).

Comment: you missed the point of this. The two inputs are ordered but the output must be ordered too.

Comment: Your solutions implement a pairwise interleave, not a merge of sorted sequences. Interleaving just happens to work for the ill-chosen `"adf"/"beg"` test case that student presented.

Comment: What Kaz said. The strings are ordered, but you don't know a priori that `(> (aref b i) (aref a (+ 1 i)))`. Your functions fail when `a = "abc"`, `b = "def"`.

Comment: Oookay, I think that the key problem here is the definition. What is the definition of "merge of sorted sequences"?

Comment: As I mentioned in another comment, given the requirements, I read "merge" as one half of [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). Which means that you want to collect the two sorted lists into a single likewise sorted list, rather than taking one element from `a` and one from `b`.