# Flatten Nests Function in Lisp - need help understanding

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I've been trying to find a way to condense nested lists into numbers that go back in the original list, but I having some trouble.

I've been looking at the flatten function (that is so widely available) which is given here:

```
(defun flatten (l)
  (cond
    ((null l) nil)
    ((atom l) (list l))
    (t (loop for a in l appending (flatten a)))))
```

I understand this example is recursion, but how does it work? It check if the element is null or an atom, but what does it do if the element falls into these conditions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my day instead of `(loop for a in l appending (g a))` we wrote `(mapcan #'g l)`. Which is equivalent to `(apply #'append (mapcar #'g l))`, more or less:

```
(defun flatten (l) 
    (if l 
        (if (atom l) 
            (list l) 
            (mapcan #'flatten l))))
```

So what does it mean in this case? Imagine you call `(flatten (list 1 2 3 4 5))`, i.e. the argument list has only *atoms* in it. *Each* atom in that list gets enclosed in a list -- becomes a *singleton* *list*, like `(1) (2)` etc. Then they are all appended together, giving us back ... the original list:

```
(  1   2   3   4   5  )

( (1) (2) (3) (4) (5) )

(  1   2   3   4   5  )
```

So flattening a list of atoms is an identity operation (in Common LISP, that's `#'identity`). Now imagine flattening a list which has some *atoms* in it as well as a *list* of *atoms*. Again, each element of the list gets transformed by `flatten` and then they are all appended together. A *list of atoms* stays as itself, as we just saw. *Atoms* get enclosed each in a list. So appending will give us back all the atoms that were on *both* levels in the nested list, now flattened:

```
(  11   12  (1 2 3 4)  13  )

( (11) (12) (1 2 3 4) (13) )

(  11   12   1 2 3 4   13  )
```

And so on and so forth, for more levels of nesting as well.

`NIL`s as elements in lists pose a problem. `NIL` is an empty list, and empty list contains nothing, so should not contribute anything. But `NIL` is also an atom. So we make a special case for it, to *not* enclose it in a singleton list - leave it as it is, so when appended, it'll just disappear.

Comment: APPLY is not a good idea, since it does not work on arbitrarily long lists.

Comment: @RainerJoswig just used it for illustration.

Comment: With the other answers of how the code executes and with Will Ness's explanation of the logic behind this program (which I wouldn't have gotten otherwise), I understand this concept now!

Comment: @RainerJoswig  What is meant by `apply` not working on a long list? Should all applications of `apply` be rewritten as recursive functions if the lists are long? and how long constitutes too long to use `apply`?

Comment: @OpenLearner: `CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT` can be as low as 50. Use `REDUCE` or something else...

Comment: @RainerJoswig so if I see this: `CL-USER> CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT
536870911` I suppose `apply` is fine, and `reduce` not necessary?

Comment: @OpenLearner (if I may interfere) I guess it's a judgment call. But, if you must write portable code, then probably not.

Comment: @OpenLearner: GCL = 64, ABCL = 50.

Comment: @RainerJoswig this is a side point but I've had my eye on ABCL for a while, is it pretty nice on JVM? a full CL implementation?

Answer (score 3):

```
(defun flatten (l)
```

Above defines a function `FLATTEN` with one argument called `L`.

```
  (cond
```

IF

```
    ((null l) nil)
```

the value of the argument `L` is the empty list, return the empty list.

```
    ((atom l) (list l))
```

or if the argument `L` is an atom (i.e. not a list), then return a list with the atom as its only item.

```
    (t
```

or else we have a non-empty list

```
       (loop for a in l
```

then loop through all the items in the list which is the value of `L`

```
        appending (flatten a)
```

and append the results of flattening each list item.

```
))))
```

Comment: @Zchpyvr: APPENDING is a feature of the LOOP macro. http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/06_ac.htm

Answer (score 2):

1. If the element you are looking at is `nil` - it is the end of the list, return nil.
2. If the element you are looking at is not a list return a list containing that element (I'm not actually sure this is a right thing to do, because given an atom, which is not a list, it would return a list with the atom, rather then the atom itself).
3. Otherwise (if it is a list), loop through all elements of it and append all the flattened sub-trees, (which you flattened by calling `flatten`), then return them.

This is short, but not the most efficient algorithm since append needs to go all the way to the end of the list in order to cons one part on the tail of another part. Below is slightly more convoluted, but looks like more efficient version of it:

```
(defun flatten (x &optional y)
  (cond
    ((null x)
     (cond
       ((null y) nil)
       ((listp (car y))
        (flatten (car y) (cdr y)))
       (t (cons (car y) (flatten (cdr y))))))
    ((listp (car x))
     (flatten (car x) (if y (list (cdr x) y) (cdr x))))
    (t (cons (car x) (flatten (cdr x) y)))))
```

The algorithm behind this function does something as follows:

1. If we have neither first element, nor the rest - we did everything, so just return `nil` (end of the list).
2. If there's no first element - split the second into the first and the rest and repeat.
3. If there is the first element, cons it into the list, if there is a second element - keep it, otherwise, select the next element and repeat.

**EDIT:** I changed the #3, because the interpretation was really vague / could be wrong.

Comment: Even after staring at your efficient flatten function for a long time.... I still don't get it. I'm a greenhorn at lisp, but I'll come back at this code another day and understand your concept. Thanks!

Comment: your code is linear-recursive instead of tree-recursive; but on implementations without [TCO % cons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons) (is there any, at all?..) it's still a full-blown recursion. Plus, it conses a lot too, recreating its input structure anew. It is possible to fix both problems in one step. [Here's one example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10311513/849891) how. :)

Comment: I think `mapcan` won't perform any extra traversals, and I'd expect `(loop for a in l nconcing (g a))` to not do any either. The maximal recursion depth for both is the nesting depth, but for your version, which replaces looping with recursion, it will be the length of the flattened list. Even without reusing the old structure (which has its place, just should be clearly marked with e.g. `nflatten` name) there's benefits to re-writing the TCO%cons code such as yours, as a *loop* instead of recursion, e.g. w/ `do` construct, building the result list in top-down manner (to avoid `reverse`).

Comment: the code in your answer right now is tail-recursive modulo cons. It can be converted into a loop by application of the standard technique, constructing the results list in top-down manner while maintaining its ending pointer. `loop` with `nconcing` could do the same, so it would only re-traverse the result of the latest recursive call to `flatten` (a *partial* solution). For a full solution, your code can be translated into a loop, or `flatten` could be re-written to return the `last` cell as well.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/smPKTSQN I tested w/ CLISP 2.38. mapcan was the fastest, your code ("linear rec") was 2nd at 1.3x time, top-down loop at 1.4x, then nconcing at 1.6x, and appending was last, 2.5x slower. nconcing clearly does something better, running 1.5x faster than appending. Very interesting to see what it'll be on your end. What are you testing it on? Please test *this code* as is, so we can compare. btw "linear rec" and "appending" run at worse cmpxties than the other three for growing data size.