# Sorting a list of pairs based on the second element in Scheme

Tags: list, sorting, scheme

Can someone give me some advice as to how to go about writing code to sort a list of pairs in increasing order based on the second element of each of the pairs? I don't have an example for you, but this seems like a simple thing to imagine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting list of pairs by the second element of the pairs in scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590732/sorting-list-of-pairs-by-the-second-element-of-the-pairs-in-scheme)

Comment: Can someone please write this function without using a built in scheme function? or is it IMPOSSIBLE?

Comment: @JohnFriedrich: step 1) write a sort function that takes a 'cmp' parameter. step 2) call it with a 'cmp' parameter that compares the second element of lists. so your question reduces simply to, how to write a sort function in scheme?

Comment: Do I then iterate through the list the amount of times equal to the length of the list?

Comment: This just makes me extremely disappointed.

Comment: @JohnFriedrich There are sorting algorithms that are faster than O(n²), so no need to be extremely disappointed. (The fastest ones have O(n log n) worst-case time; I believe it's impossible to go any faster.)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young surely you forgot about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_sorting ... :)

Comment: @WillNess Nice! Thanks for the heads-up. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to write a mergesort.

```
(define (mgsort ls cmp)
  (cond
    ((or (null? ls) (null? (cdr ls)))
       ls)
    ; right? ... then,
    (else 
      (split ls '() '() cmp))))
```

The most basic tool in dealing with lists is structural recursion:

```
(define (split ls a b cmp)
  (cond 
    ((null? ls) 
       (merge (mgsort a cmp) (mgsort b cmp) cmp))
    (else
       (split (cdr ls) b (cons (car ls) a) cmp))))
```

What's left now it just to write `merge` – a function that will merge, like "zipping", its two arguments which are sorted lists, so the result is a sorted list too.

```
(define (merge a b cmp)
  (cond 
    ((null? a) b)
    ((null? b) ....)
    ((cmp (car a) (car b))   ; right?
       (cons   
          ... ;; what? ... with what??
          (merge (cdr a) ......)))
    (else
       (cons
          ... 
          (merge a ......)))))
```

Testing:

```
(mgsort (list 3 1 5 4 6 2 3) <)
;Value 12: (1 2 3 3 4 5 6)

(mgsort (list (cons 3 1) (cons 4 5) (cons 6 2)) (lambda(a b) (< (cdr a) (cdr b))))
;Value 13: ((3 . 1) (6 . 2) (4 . 5))
```

---

cf. [how would one merge two strings that are ordered alphabetically in lisp using recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304726/how-would-one-merge-two-strings-that-are-ordered-alphabetically-in-lisp-using-re/10311513#10311513) for an efficient top-down merge function (though in Common Lisp, and nominally for strings, but it really works with lists inside), a by-hand implementation of tail recursion modulo cons optimization technique.

Comment: Thanks, this looks more like something I can understand since I am relatively new to Scheme.